# Know any good UI/UX jokes?

Tags: user-behavior, search, intuition

Are there any UI jokes out there?  Seems like other industries have their own jokes, I was trying to think of UI design, couldn't come up with much - but that's not to say they don't exist?

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to UX! Unfortunately this question is not a good fit for this website - you can read more in the [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq). However, you're more than welcome to join the chatroom and ask it there. I know at least one UI joke :)

Comment: We need to get the public wiki feature going!

Comment: @DA01 Agreed, but IMHO this wouldn't be on-topic there either :)

Comment: Wow... anyone else think that this site could benefit from taking itself a little less seriously?

Comment: @GordonKennedy, just like any other stack exchange site, there are rules that need to be followed so that we don't drown the signal with noise. As much as I enjoy jokes, they are not what I'm looking to find at [UX.SE]

Comment: Booo  :)  Actually I'm usually a fairly constructive poster, and have read the guidelines, and figured this question would get closed, but then again, I reasoned it was good clean fun, related to the theme (at least more so than unicorns).  I'll keep the topmost button securely fastened in the future.  *bows, scrolls off to stage left*

Comment: Even the original SO site has joke related questions (wiki) in it.

Comment: @DA01 - Community wiki is not for things that would otherwise be off-topic.

Comment: I understand that we have varying opinions as to what is on/off topic.

Comment: And yes, let's not take ourselves too seriously. Jokes about UX are obviously UX-related.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: Just got one: bad kerning -> keming. Lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the UX drinking game: http://www.uxdrinkinggame.com/, as well as the classic "How many UX designers does it take to screw in a lightbulb" http://www.quora.com/How-many-UX-experts-does-it-take-to-screw-in-a-light-bulb

Comment: And the only answer...is the winner!  Best, wittiest, fastest, most imaginative.  But seriously, cheers.  That's pretty funny (both).